# Is there a way to set "another" PATH variable?

Tags: linux, unix, path

I know that if I have a custom path `CUSTOM_PATH=/some/custom/path/`, then i just do `export PATH=$PATH:$CUSTOM_PATH` in order to have system-wide access to the executables in `/some/custom/path`.

But, for some complicated reasons, it would be great if I could define `$CUSTOM_PATH`, not append it to `$PATH` but still have its contents searched as if it were appended to `$PATH`.

This is what I mean by "another" PATH variable: a path which is searched like $PATH, but defined separately. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, but what are the complicated reasons? Maybe, there is a different way to address your issue

Comment: If you explain the complicated reasons we might be able to come up with a solution, either with an alternative to `PATH` or something else entirely.

Comment: I have a conda environment where, upon activation, I'm appending something to `PATH`.  Upon deactivation, I need `PATH` to go back to what it was prior to activation. I tried using an intermediate variable like `OLDPATH=PATH`, but conda adds stuff to `PATH` before running my activation scripts, so restoring `PATH=OLDPATH` later still keeps the stuff conda added.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: No.

If this were possible, then it might be something like:

```
export CUSTOM_PATH=/usr/local/bin
export PATH='/usr/bin:/bin:$CUSTOM_PATH'
```

That would put the literal string `"$CUSTOM_PATH"` into your `$PATH`. You could then change the value of `$CUSTOM_PATH`, without touching `$PATH`, and implicitly update your system's search path.

But it doesn't work that way. The relevant library functions (`execlp` et al) treat the value of the `$PATH` environment variable as a colon-delimited sequence of literal directory names. It doesn't do any kind of expansion on those names.

You'll just have to update `$PATH` any time you want to change the system search path. (You can maintain the value of `$PATH` any way you like, including incorporating the values of other environment variables.)